# correct way define an association so that i can alter data through the association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing something wrong and it's either in the method i'm trying to alter data with or the way i have an association defined.

```
class Hive
  has_many :bees, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Bee
  belongs_to :hive
  attr_accessor :alive, :name
end

>h = Hive.create()
>h.bees.where(:alive => false).count = 100 #created from after_initialize
>h.bees.where(:alive => false).each {|b|b.name="Walter"} 
>h.bees.where(:name => "Walter").count = 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: After iterating through the collection and altering each of them the change isn't reflected.  I'd like to see 100 bees named Walter in the above example.

Comment: What does >h.bees.count return?

Comment: 101.  This is just conceptual, i'm having trouble with this when writing a test for a validation and setting values on data through the relationship then testing for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick...

```
h.bees.each do |bee|
  bee.name = "Walter"
  bee.save!
end
```

If there is no validation for

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

Comment: there's no validation like that and this looks like the same thing i have up there without the condition.  i tried the do/end instead of the block and it had the same effect in rails console

Comment: the save does work, i'm hoping i can avoid adding the transaction but now that two people have suggested it maybe that all i can do.  i suppose it's better this way to support optimistic locking

Answer (score 2):

Try calling save() inside your block to persist the changes.

Comment: that will work but i'd rather not create the transaction overhead if i can maintain a reference to the same objs through the relationship